# SQLFORM Self-Referencing Table Displaying Formatted Value

Tags: web2py

Is it possible using a SQLFORM to have a recursive table pull the formatted value as it does for non-recursive tables?

Two examples below have the same result, a parent field that displays the underlying ID value, as opposed to the formatted name value.

**Model**

```
db.define_table('cat',
                Field('name', type='string', label='Name'),
                Field('parent', 'reference cat', label='Parent'),
                format='%(name)s',
               )
```

**Controller**

```
def index(): 
    form=SQLFORM(db.cat)

    if form.process().accepted:
        response.flash = "Updates Accepted"

    return locals()
def manage():
    form=SQLFORM.grid(db.cat, user_signature=False)

    return locals()
```

Comment: Because the table does not yet exist at the time the reference field is created (and therefore no `format` attribute available), you will have to manually define the `IS_IN_DB` validator and `represent` attribute as part of the field definition.

Answer (score 1):

The answer provided by Anthony in the comment ended up working.

Changing the model to the below works for the index function.  I needed the IS_NULL_OR in my use case to allow for the value to be missing as well.

```
db.define_table('cat',
                Field('name', type='string', label='Name'),
                Field('parent', 'reference cat', label='Parent'),
                format='%(name)s',
               )
db.cat.parent.requires = IS_NULL_OR(IS_IN_DB(db, 'cat.id', '%(name)s'))
```

As Anthony indicated, the represent attribute is also needed for the SQLFORM.grid to display the correct value, the above model results in the id variable being displayed in the manage function.

In the manage function, I added a represent to the parent field which can either be the literal word none if it is null or a lookup.

```
def manage():
    db.cat.parent.represent = lambda id, r: db.cat[id].name if id else 'None'
    form=SQLFORM.grid(db.cat, 
                      user_signature=False)

    return locals()
```